# Positioning of my website in IE is totally wrong

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, positioning

Does anyone know a solution to my problem or where I should look for this to work? 
I am working on a website ( http://www.awww.nl ) and I got all the positioning of the elements the way I wanted... but when I checked in IE most of the positioning is totally off!

Especially on the post pages (for example: http://awww.nl/superlieve-luiaard/ ) the design is moving all the way to the right in IE (in chrome on my Imac everything is correct) And on the homepage the button to add pictures disapears.

I tried to fix it by using different Doctypes but that didn't work.

Comment: Have you tried creating a different CSS for IE?

Comment: It has nothing to do with php.

Comment: check out properly for css esp in ie

Comment: Every web browser differs when they come to display a web page. that's why there are several tools in HTML/CSS to apply one style according to the web browser like special special css properties for chrome, ff, ie etc.

Answer (score 1):

Your website is rendering in [Quirks mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quirks_mode), probably because of a doctype mistake.

I do not recognize your current doctype:

```
<!DOCTYPE XHTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
```

Can you try changing your doctype to this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

If that doesn't fix it, then add to the `<head>` tag:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
```

This should render it in the highest version available. However, I would recommend that you look for the doctype mistake and fix it as it is the root of the cause.

Comment: I do not recognize your doctype... this is the problem.

Comment: I added the doctype you suggested and the <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />  to the head but still the positioning is off. Does IE not recognize my padding or does it have problems with using floats? Is there maybe a different way for IE to recognize?

Comment: Thanks for the help. I noticed a overflow: hidden on the div that was displayed in a wrong way and after removing that the biggest problem was fixed.